# Can I use an old version of IIS and still be secure?

Tags: iis

I've a site and it's using IIS 8.5

Can I be secure?

IIS 8.5 is secure or it can be hacked easily?

When should I update IIS and when shouldn't I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to wikipedia IIS 8.5 is included in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 and both systems are still supported for some time. This way IIS 8.5 also receives updates and if you always update the server by itself will probably be secure enough until the end of support.

But, the main attack vector is usually not the web server itself (i.e. IIS) but the web application served by the web server or the database used by this web application. Thus if you run some insecure CMS (i.e. Wordpress without latest updates) or other insecure web application on your system it does not matter if IIS by itself is secure since it will not protect the insecure web application.